# SQL temp table creation with parameter in FastReport VCL 5

Tags: sql, delphi, fastreport

since several request in my report use the same subquery, I wrote a DBXQuery named qCreateTemp that prepares a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp AS SELECT * FROM acomplexrequest WHERE afield = :avalue
```

I defined avalue as an (integer) parameter of the request with  value.

First I linked it to a dummy MasterData band, but FastReports complains the request doesn't return a Cursor.

So I tried to call it explicitly from the script code, first simply as:

```
qCreateTemp.ExecSQL;
```

Then noticing the request's parameter was not passed, I tried:

```
qCreateTemp.Params.ParamByName('avalue').Value := <avariable>;
qCreateTemp.ExecSQL;
```

but I get an error "Could not convert a variant of type (Null) into type (Integer)"

What's the best/correct way to do this ? Thanks !

Comment: Did you tried qCreateTemp.Params.ParamByName('avalue').AsInteger := <avariable> ?

Comment: What value of avariable variable?
Try `ShowMessage(<avariable>);
qCreateTemp.Params.ParamByName('avalue').Value := <avariable>;`
Do you use latest FR 5.6.3?

Comment: @ gpi yes, <avariable> has the correct value ... I have V 5.6 pro @PatrickPrémartin : yes I tried, not better :-(

Comment: can you give us more code ?

Comment: For FastReport you need a SELECT * FROM temp in the band.
The CREATE TEMP TABLE seems to be good. Did you tried it manually ?

Comment: @PatrickPrémartin : yes sure the CREATE TEMP TABLE works either manually or when I replace the :avalue by its value in the request. The problem is precisely I cannot reference it in a band since it doesn't return a cursor, and since FR doesn't allow to put several requests in a single one, I have to call the request from the FR script using ExecSQL ... But the parameter passing mechanism doesn't seem to work in this case ...

Comment: @PatrickPrémartin : I think all the reguired code is given : just create a "CREATE TEMP TABLE" SQL request with a parameter in a FR form, try to attach it to a band (it won't work...) and then try to launch the request from the script ...